# IP whitelisting according to new Magento best practices

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

Recently Magento updated the post: "Protect your Magento Installation from Password Guessing", see: https://magento.com/security/best-practices/protect-your-magento-installation-password-guessing-new-update

While in the original post they advised to put the following in the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/ADMIN_PANEL_LOCATION [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/DOWNLOADER [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/CATALOG [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/ORDER [NC]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.4

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^5.6.7.8

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Now they seem to recommend the following approach:

```
# Whitelist an IP address for the admin panel
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?admin/ - [L,R=403]

# Whitelist an IP address for the RSS feed
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/?)?rss/ - [L,R=403]
```

and put this in the ./downloader/.htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I am not much expert on this subject, so I was wondering:

1. if both the first and second method are good for Magento 1
2. what the difference really is between one approach over the other
   and if there's one which is better

Answer (score 1):

While both of them are basically ok the second one is still better due to the following reason:

With a return code `302` in the `RewriteRule` you **redirect** all these requests (which should not be allowed) to your shops' homepage again, which results in an additional request. If someone starts brute-forcing on these URLs you will generate an **additional request**, so basically you would support your own DoS.

With a HTTP return code of `403` you might end up on basic 403 page (more or less fancy, depending on server configuration) but there **won't be any further requests** to your Magento.

Comment: If I change [R=302,L] from the first method to [R=403,L], are the two methods above the same?